# Android : How to Pass the JSON object From AsncTask class to the Main Class

Tags: java, android, json, android-asynctask

I have a `JSONObject` receiving from an API call within a `AsyncTask` class. I want to pass that JSON object to my `MainActivity` class to show the `JSONObject` data in the GUI. I found some solutions throughout some searches and came up with a close solution. But when i access from the `MainActivity` class it says the `JSONObject` is null. What have i dont wrong here? Is this the best way to do this ?

Following is my `AsyncTask` Class

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
import org.json.JSONObject;

/**
 * Created by Nisal on 13-Sep-17.
 */

public class GetStationsAPICall extends AsyncTask<String, Void, JSONObject> {

    Context ctx;
    JSONObject responseObj;
    String result;

    public interface AsyncResponse {
        void processFinish(JSONObject output);
    }

    public AsyncResponse delegate = null;

    public GetStationsAPICall(AsyncResponse delegate){
        this.delegate = delegate;
    }

//    GetStationsAPICall(Context ctx){
//        this.ctx=ctx;
//    }

    @Override
    protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... params) {

        String method = params[0];

        if(method.equals("getStations")){

            try {
                HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                String getURL = "http://api.gate.com/?lang=en";
                HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(getURL);
                httpGet .setHeader("Authorization", "Bearer 690");

                HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpGet);
                HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();
                if (resEntity != null) {
                    //parse response.
                    Log.e("Response", EntityUtils.toString(resEntity));
//                    return "Successfully Connected!";
                }else{
//                    return "Connection Failed!";
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
//                return "Connection Failed!";
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject obj) {
        delegate.processFinish(obj);
    }
}
```

Following is my `MainActivity` Class

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.json.JSONObject;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements GetStationsAPICall.AsyncResponse{

    Button btnSearch;
    String method = "getStations";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        GetStationsAPICall getStations = new GetStationsAPICall(this);
        new GetStationsAPICall(this).execute(method);
    }

    public void searchClicked(View view){
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Search Clicked",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void processFinish(JSONObject output) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"ProcessFinish",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        if(output != null){
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"not null",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this," null",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

I can get the `JSONObject` within the `AsyncTask` class, But when i try to pass it to the `MainActivity` class and use it there. The JSONObject becomes `null`. What have I done wrong here?

Comment: Because you return nothing else than null in your doInBackground ?

Comment: Check my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although I'm sure you got a working solution, I wouldn't recommend making your activity into a listener that could potentially leak it (what happens if you press the home button before you get a result back?). Also, as mentioned previously, the main problem you had was that you were returning `null` from your `doInBackground` function. So let's address these two issues for now:

**MainActivity.java**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager;

import org.json.JSONObject;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    Button btnSearch;
    String method = "getStations";
    BroadcastReceiver apiListener;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        BroadcastReceiver apiListener = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                String output = intent.getStringExtra("API_Response); //Getting the string extra you input earlier in the AsyncTask.
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"ProcessFinish",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                if(output != null){
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"not null",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this," null",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        };

        //Since you are starting your AsyncTask here, might want to set up the receiver prior to calling the task.
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(apiListener, new IntentFilter(""));

        GetStationsAPICall getStations = new GetStationsAPICall(this);
        new GetStationsAPICall(this).execute(method);
    }

    public void searchClicked(View view){
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Search Clicked",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    //Registers the receiver whenever this acitivty is currently being shown or about to.
    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this)
            .registerReceiver(apiListener, new IntentFilter("StationsAPI")); //This is the intent filter this receiver will be listening for
    }

    //This stops the receiver from listening when the activity is no longer shown.
    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(apiListener);
    }
}
```

I made quite a few changes with some comments describing them. The most important thing to notice here is that this Activity is no longer a listener, as I've replaced that functionality for a [`LocalBroadcastManager`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager.html). Using this, I can register as many `BroadcastReceiver` objects as I wish to handle the response of the AsyncTask, without worrying about interrupting the process of the AsyncTask.

As you can see, I used an `IntentFilter` to let the manager know that only intents with this action ("StationsAPI") should go to the receiver I registered (`apiListener`). Also, so I don't have a situation where I potentially leak the activity, I unregister the receiver as soon as the activity is no longer visible, and re-register when it is visible again.

**GetStationsAPICall.java**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
import org.json.JSONObject;

/**
* Created by Nisal on 13-Sep-17.
*/

public class GetStationsAPICall extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    LocalBroadcastManager localBroadcastManager; //This is the manager to send a result back to your activity

    GetStationsAPICall(Context ctx){
        localBroadcastManager = LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(ctx); //No matter where you call this, it is the same object throughout your app.
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        String method = params[0];

        if(method.equals("getStations")){

            try {
                HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                String getURL = "http://api.gate.com/?lang=en";
                HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(getURL);
                httpGet .setHeader("Authorization", "Bearer 690");

                HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpGet);
                HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();
                if (resEntity != null) {
                    //parse response.
                    String responseString = EntityUtils.toString(resEntity);
                    Log.e("Response", responseString;
                    return responseString; //This will be the parameter of your onPostExecute method
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String obj) {
        localBroadcastManager
            .sendBroadcast( //Sending the intent with the response!
                new Intent("StationsAPI") //Remember that IntentFilter? Here is where you declare where to send intent.
                    .putExtra("API_Response", obj)); //This is the extra data you want to send to your receivers.
    }
}
```

As with the `MainActivity` class above, I've commented the sections with the changes I made. The `JSONObject` class isn't parcelable, so instead of creating it and then reconverting it into something I can place inside the `Intent`, I just left it as a `String` object, and returned that value in the `doInBackground` method.

Now whenever you call your `GetStationsAPICall` task, you should get the response in your `MainActivity` (or any other receiver with an `IntentFilter` for "API_Response"). Although this solution itself isn't perfect (what if the user rotates the device?), it should help avoid some of the pitfalls Android has to offer.

Answer (score 1):

You are recreating the `GetStationsAPICall` object again before executing it. So your `AsyncResponse` object will be null.

Change your code like this:

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        GetStationsAPICall getStations = new GetStationsAPICall(this);
        getStations.execute(method);
    }
```

Comment: thanks you. WIth your answer and with some other changes i managed to do this.